# connman1.11 unable to fetch all services and technology

Tags: c, linux

I am new to use connman. I have installed connman1.11 on `UBUNTU11.10` which is running in ORACLE VM virtual Box.

While running `connmanctl` under client, if I request to get Services, I get only Wired and not other services like Wifi. If I request technologies, I get following error:

> *Method "GetTechnologies" with signature "" on interface "net.connman.Manager" doesn't exist*

Similarly for connect, scan etc.
kindly assist, what changes I have to make